# Como realizar update em registros marcados com checkbox em um while

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, while

Não estou conseguindo efetuar o UPDATE dos campos que estão apenas selecionados pelo CHECKBOX, o que eu consegui desenvolver esta logo abaixo:

**BD.SQL**

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `seq_acessos` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
USE `seq_acessos`;

CREATE TABLE `teste2` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `teste1` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `teste2` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `teste2` (`id`, `teste1`, `teste2`) VALUES
(5, '02', '22'),
(6, '03', '33'),
(7, '04', '44');


ALTER TABLE `teste2`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);


ALTER TABLE `teste2`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=8;
```

**INDEX.PHP**

```
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', TRUE );

    $host = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $bd = "teste";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $senha, $bd);

    if($mysqli->connect_errno){
        echo "Falha na Conexão: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error;
    }



$sql_code = "SELECT * FROM teste2";
$sql_query = $mysqli->query($sql_code) or die($mysqli->error);
?>
<br>
<br>
<form action="" method="post">
<?php while($linha = $sql_query->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[cb][]" value="<?php echo $linha['id']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="teste[teste1][]" value="<?php echo $linha['teste1']; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="teste[teste2][]" value="<?php echo $linha['teste2']; ?>">
<?php } ?>  
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>
<?php

if(isset($_POST)){
    $field      = $_POST;
    $count      = count($field[teste]);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){

$up .= "UPDATE table SET teste1 = {$field['teste']['teste1'][$i]}, teste2 = {$field['teste']['teste2'][$i]} WHERE id = $linha[id] \n";

    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($up);   
    print_r($_POST);    

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <?php 
    $linha = [];

    $linha[1] = array("id" => 1, 'field' => "valor", 'field2' => "valor2");
    $linha[2] = array("id" => 2, 'field' => "valor", 'field2' => "valor2");
    $linha[3] = array("id" => 3, 'field' => "valor", 'field2' => "valor2");
    $linha[4] = array("id" => 4, 'field' => "valor", 'field2' => "valor2");
    $linha[5] = array("id" => 5, 'field' => "valor", 'field2' => "valor2");

    echo '<form action="" method="post">';
    echo '<ul>';
    for ($i=1; $i <= count($linha); $i++) { 

        echo '<li><input type="checkbox" name="teste[ex'.$i.'][id]"      value="'.$linha[$i]["id"].'"></li>
        <li><input type="text"  name="teste[ex'.$i.'][field]" value="'.$linha[$i]["field"].'"></li>
        <li><input type="text"  name="teste[ex'.$i.'][field2]" value="'.$linha[$i]["field2"].'"></li>';
    }
    echo '</ul><br><br>
       <input type="submit" value="OK">
    </form>';

    if (isset($_POST['teste'])) {
       $data = $_POST['teste']; 
       if ($data != null) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                if (isset($value['id']) && !empty($value['id'])) {
                    $query = "UPDATE table SET field =".$value['field'].",field2 =".$value['field2']." WHERE id= ".$value['id'];
                    $query = rtrim($query, ", ");
                    echo "<pre>$query";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Lucas, obrigado pela atenção, mas não consegui testar sua idéia, mesmo acrescentando o fechamento do FOR, a $query não esta sendo exibida.

Comment: @CristianoIglesias, tente novamente refiz os ajustes.

Comment: Só para constar que ficou exatamente como eu queria, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi você quer pegar os valores que estão nos `inputs` do tipo `text` de acordo com o checkbox marcado. Para isso você tem que ver se o checkbox correspondente foi marcado e pegar o valor dele que será usado como referência para pegar os dos `text`. Segue um exemplo:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $checkbox = $_POST["teste"]['cb'];


    if(is_array($checkbox) && !empty($checkbox)){

        $up = '';

        foreach($checkbox as $key=>$value){

            $teste1 = $_POST['teste']["teste1"][$key];
            $teste2 = $_POST['teste']["teste2"][$key];

            $up .= "UPDATE table SET teste1 = '".$teste1."', teste2 = '".$teste2."' WHERE id = '".$value."' <br />";
        }

        echo $up;
    }
  }
?>

<?php
error_reporting ( E_ALL );
ini_set( 'display_errors', TRUE );

    $host = "localhost";
    $usuario = "root";
    $senha = "";
    $bd = "teste";

    $mysqli = new mysqli($host, $usuario, $senha, $bd);

    if($mysqli->connect_errno){
        echo "Falha na Conexão: (".$mysqli->connect_errno.") ".$mysqli->connect_error;
    }



$sql_code = "SELECT * FROM teste2";
$sql_query = $mysqli->query($sql_code) or die($mysqli->error);
?>
<form action="" method="post">

    <?php while($linha = $sql_query->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="teste[cb][]" value="<?php echo $linha['id'];?>">
    <input type="text" name="teste[teste1][]" value="<?php echo $linha['teste1'];?>">
    <input type="text" name="teste[teste2][]" value="<?php echo $linha['teste2'];?>">
    <br />
    <?php } ?>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Sim, preciso alterar somente as linhas que estiverem marcadas com o checkbox, no exemplo acima o BD possui 3 registros:
Efetuei um teste com a alteração que você fez e agora esta gerando o UPDATE somente dos checkbox marcados, perfeito, mas não esta identificando os valores corretos dos imputs.  
Efetuei um teste alterando o 1 e o 3 registro e o resultado foi este:  
UPDATE table SET teste1 = '02', teste2 = '22' WHERE id = '2'  
UPDATE table SET teste1 = '03', teste2 = '33' WHERE id = '4'

Comment: Vou tentar detalhar um pouco mais:    Se eu marcar os três checkbox é criado corretamente os UPDATES:  UPDATE table SET teste1 = '02', teste2 = '22' WHERE id = '2'  UPDATE table SET teste1 = '03', teste2 = '33' WHERE id = '3'  UPDATE table SET teste1 = '04', teste2 = '44' WHERE id = '4'    Mas como mensionei anteriormente, se eu efetuar somente as alterações do 1 e o 3 campos, o resultado é este:  UPDATE table SET teste1 = '02', teste2 = '22' WHERE id = '2'  UPDATE table SET teste1 = '03', teste2 = '33' WHERE id = '4'    O UPDATE é criado com os valores incorretos.